# What is the difference between random variable and uncertainty?

Tags: probability-theory, random

Please help me to find the difference between random variable and uncertainty?
Can use the formula for the area of random variables (expectation, derivation,...)in the field of nonrandom variables (uncertainty with probability)?
How can I solve Z=a/(b+s^2) where a,b are uncertainty with probability and s are  Laplace variable(without probability)
For example a=[2-5]with normal distribution and B=[1-3] normal distribution.
Please be careful a,b are Non-random nature but they have probability. Hence, I think we can use formula for the area of random variables to solve problem. Don't you?

Comment: A random variable is when the outcome is numeric.  So flipping a coin doesn't give a random variable, it just gives a head or a tail. But if you map head to one and tail to zero then it is a random variable.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/275a-notes-0-foundations-of-probability-theory/

Comment: I might be badly wrong, but as of my understanding, a random variable is just a measurable but otherwise unknown function.

Comment: Dr. Gharib, what do you mean by solve? If a and b are random then $Z$ is random too. s I guess is just a constant. / @Jack Nice!